# Is it valid C to declare a struct and define values enclosed in {}?

Tags: c, macos

Is it valid C to declare a struct and define values enclosed in {}?

```
struct name new_name[] {
    {"value1"},
    {"value2"},
    {"value3"},
}
```

Where:

```
struct name {
    union {
        char *value1;
    } n_u;

    char *value2;
}
```

Comment: Post the code inside your question. Don't make questions which depend on external links to be meaningful. Better yet, make your question generic. There is absolutely no reason to link to that file. Post the relevant syntax and ask "Is this valid syntax?"

Comment: I tried to post the code, but couldn't get the syntax right for it to be accepted as a question.

Comment: Indent the code by 4 spaces, or select it and click the `{}` button. As it stands, you've not even provided a line number, just a link to a 600 line file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've posted is invalid because it's missing an equals sign before the initializer (and also trailing semicolons). Otherwise, it's legal but somewhat hard to read because it doesn't initialize every field, and doesn't use a full set of braces. In a fully-braced initializer, you'll have a pair of braces around the list of values for every array, struct, or union. In this case you have an array of structs with unions in them, so there should be 3 levels of braces for optimum readability. An equivalent with everything spelled out is:

```
struct name new_name[] = {
    {{"value1"}, NULL},
    {{"value2"}, NULL},
    {{"value3"}, NULL},
};
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness / best practice explanation.  Just to confirm this compiles right - struct containing char* then init-ing to a string literal?

Comment: Also, there's not really a point in declaring a 1 member union unless you need bit fields or you're trying to do something funny like force your member to align at word boundries.. which doesn't matter in this case because your union has a single `char *` member so it's 4 or 8 bytes anyway.

Comment: @djechlin yes it is allowed to initalize a char * with a string literal. The string will be placed in a separate memory area, which may not be writable, so it's better to use a const char * for the type if you can.